# Dynamic import with variable is not working

Tags: webpack, parceljs

I am trying to do this:

```
const new_language = "en-US"
await import(`/languages/${new_language}.json`)
```

But got the following error:

```
Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: 'text/html' is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.
```

I am using **Parcel bundler** and installed and imported the `babel-polyffil`

Comment: Are you using `await` in top level of the file? Meaning its not inside a function/class

Comment: Nope its inside async function